# showing $\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^{n-1}}{n} $

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to show

$\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} = -\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x e^{kx} = \frac{\ln(e^x)}{e^x-1} = -\frac{\ln[1-(1-e^x)]}{1-e^x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^{n-1}}{n} $

The first step seems trivial, what i am confused is the process of 
\begin{align}
-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}xe^{kx} = \frac{\ln(e^x)}{e^x-1}
\end{align}
and the last step 
\begin{align}
-\frac{\ln[1-(1-e^x)]}{1-e^x} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^{n-1}}{n}
\end{align}

Can you give me some idea for these steps?

Comment: What is it you are missing, that $x=\ln(e^x)$ or the expansion of $\ln(1-t)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In order to show the identity
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(1-e^x\right)^{n-1}}{n}\qquad\qquad |1-e^x|<1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

we recall that

\begin{align*}
  \ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<1
  \end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> x&=\ln(e^x)=\ln(1-(1-e^x))\\
> &=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (1-e^x)^n\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad |1-e^x|<1\\
> \end{align*}
>   and after division by $1-e^x$ with $x \neq 0$ we get (1)
>   \begin{align*}
>   \frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (1-e^x)^{n-1}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad x<\ln 2,x\neq 0
>   \end{align*}

Note, it is not necessary to consider  a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*. In fact the representation in this case is different from the series representation in (1) since the radius of convergence is different.
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty xe^{kx}\qquad\qquad |e^x|<1\quad\text{resp.}\quad x<0
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As $x=\ln({e^x})$ ,
$$
\begin{align}
-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}xe^{kx}\end{align} =\frac{x}{e^x-1}= \frac{\ln(e^x)}{e^x-1}
$$
And as $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$ ,
$$
-\frac{\ln[1-(1-e^x)]}{1-e^x} = -\frac{(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^n}{n})}{1-e^x}=\frac{1}{1-e^x}.\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-e^x)^{n-1}}{n}
$$

Comment: Someting is missing in your explanation : the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{kx}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(e^{x})^n=\frac{1}{1-e^x}$ is the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think that nothing is missing here it is just a different way of thinking then yours
**and** sorry i am unable to link your fact with the question or answer

Comment: If you think that what I have indicated is not useful, that's OK. If my precision has brought some supplementary help to the OP, I will be happy.

Comment: @JeanMarie: It should be noted, that a geometric series expansion has a different region of convergence. Regards,

Comment: @Markus Scheuer I have had a look at your proof, and I understand your point.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Great! Thanks for your reply.